# Rewrite URL to remove first page pagination using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an paginated list of articles and my search engine is indexing the first page twice as /articles and /articles?start=1.

I want to write an .htaccess rewrite rule to rewrite any requests for /articles?start=1 to /articles to stop this from happening.

There are a couple of other article based paginated lists on the site, so i need to match just the parameter rather that the full url, so that the rule will work on thse urls also.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \/articles\/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} start=1
RewriteRule (.*)$ /index.php\?
```

I am assuming `articles` is a directory.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a necro, but I just found this question via Google when looking for something else.

Recently, Google offered up way more control over how URL parameters affect their indexing of your site.  Go to [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/webmasters/) and set up your site.

Google will crawl your site and add a list of URL parameters its aware of (and I beleive you can add your own to the list).  You can specify how the URL parameters affect your page (pagination, filtering, internal etc) which in turn tells Google how to index it.

In this case, you'll be able to say that *start* should be either ignored, indexed only once, or treated how you see fit to make sure it only appears how its meant to in the index.

This helps Google and also helps you, so its entirely win-win.